# Have we ever used the word "outcome" for regressors?

Tags: econometrics, nonexpert

From my understanding, we normally use the word "outcome" for dependent variables( aka regressand), but today, when I look at [this document](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/dae/multivariate-regression-analysis/) it seems to me that they use "outcome" for independent variable. I am wondering if my understanding if correct or I fall into any fallacy.

> As the name implies, multivariate regression is a technique that
> estimates a single regression model with **more than one outcome
> variable**. When there is more than one predictor variable in a
> multivariate regression model, the model is a multivariate multiple
> regression.

Comment: @EB3112 , I understand what you mean regarding the "outcome variable" meaning, I mean, the way they use the word confusing me. From reading the first sentence, it seems to me that they estimate a single regression model with more than one dependent variables.

Comment: There are instances in which there are more than one outcome variables. And in fact, it looks like on your document they've estimated an M-ANOVA model in which there are multiple outcomes variables such as 'motivation' 'self-concept' etc. So, here, the authors are correct in specifiying that there are multiple outcome variables. ANOVA-type analysis is typically used in nonparametric settings (such as medicine). More likely examples of regression with multiple outcomes in economics, would be something like 'vector autoregression'

Comment: Thanks @EB3112, you are right, they use ```manova``` approach and run the same set of explanatory variables for two outcomes variables simultaneously

Comment: It is good to know because it is the first time I know that we can run the regression for two outcome variables at the same time.

Comment: And it look like something similar to joint test .

Comment: Yeah, you're right. ANOVA isn't far off something like an F-test in a non-parametric setting.